# Installing rtl8192eu but can't get rid of rtl88XXau

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, internet

I have **TP-Link USB Wifi adapter** which I use on Ubuntu 20.04. The problem is that it's very slow so I'm trying to install this: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

Although I followed the steps I still don't see `rt68192eu` in `sudo lshw -c network`

```
milano@milano-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -c network;
[sudo] password for milano: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: 70:85:c2:7c:b8:ff
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:125 memory:a3300000-a331ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlx9848276ea01e
       serial: 98:48:27:6e:a0:1e
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88XXau ip=192.168.100.7 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

Please, can you help me? I also tried to manually edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` adding:

```
blacklist rtl8xxxu
blacklist rtl88XXau
```

But the output is still the same (after reboot).

**EDIT**

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info
```

returns this:

https://gist.github.com/futilestudio/513b81ca890cb8058179c2055498dc81

Comment: I doubt that installing an older, less well supported driver will make your wireless faster. I'd rather address the speed than try another driver. Please edit your post to provide full diagnstics from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: @chili555 The output is too big to paste it here (char limit), so I've created a gist: https://gist.github.com/futilestudio/513b81ca890cb8058179c2055498dc81

Comment: Try blacklist 88XXau as that is the drivers name in the script results, but I would advise against it as it is the driver that is making the wifi work.  The rtl8192eu driver doesn't cover your device